# How do I use flask-sqlalchemy to pass a date and time into a Postgres table

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am using `flask-sqlalchemy` and `flask-wtforms` to ask a user to pick a date and time.  I then want to pass this date and time as UTC into my PostgreSQL database using `flask-sqlalchemy`.

My main problem is that I cannot find the documentation that helps me understand the process of the fields I need in my `events` table and the format I need to pass from my `wtform`.  I have used a `.datetimepicker` in my HTML and my form.py line looks like this.

`eventstart = DateTime('Event Start', validators=[DataRequired()])`

I have followed a few examples but if anyone can point me in the right direction, I would be very grateful.

```
 __tablename__ = 'events'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    eventname = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    eventstart = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    eventstop = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False)
    timeblock = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

Answer (score 0):

The fields for DateTime are correctly defined in your DB table 'events'.
The format for storing the datetime should be like **2022-03-21 19:04:14**.

You can get eventstart into this format or can also use pandas.to_datetime to reformat it which can be stored into the table.